# How to create a postmapping method in spring so that clients need only enter a partial object instead of full object?

Tags: java, spring, post, jackson, pojo

Here is my pojo

```
// Removed getters, setters, constructors for brevity, Also don't worry about Movie pojo
@Document
public class WatchList {
    @Id
    private String _id;
    private List<Movie> currentlyWatching;
    private List<Movie> completed;
}
```

Now in my rest controller I have a postmapping method like this

```
// Here id is the id of watchList I want to update
@PostMapping("/{id}/update")
public void updateItem(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody WatchList watchList){
    WatchList old = watchListRepo.findById(id).get();  
    // Now update old with contents from watchList. However only change those fields that are sent from @RequestBody. How to do this?
}
```

So from postman, I am sending a post request to this endpoint(with the id to change of course) with body like this

```
{
    "currentlyWatching" : [...some new stuff]
}
```

However, my `old` watchList pojo already has stuff like this:

```
{
    "currentlyWatching" : [...some old stuff],
    "completed" : [...some old stuff],
}
```

Now once this method gets done, I want my pojo to turn into this

```
{
    "currentlyWatching" : [...some new stuff], // so this gets updated from post request
    "completed" : [...some old stuff], // this stays the same since post request body did not contain this field called completed
}
```

So, I essentially only want to update `currentlyWatching` field when client sends a post request with body containing `currentlyWatching`. Now I can of course check for fields and map it manually, but my `WatchList` is not as simple as shown here. It has more than 10 fields(not just `currentlyWatching` and `completed`). I want some dynamic easy way to do this. Also manual way of doing this would probably not be best design practice anyway.

`Extra Info`:
I am using `spring data mongo` so that `@Document` annotation or repository class(extends MongoRepository) are from mongo jars. Also if it matters at all, the `Movie` pojo is another pojo that has nested properties. However I want a way to do this dynamically, so `Movie` pojo could be anything. Hence the solution that we figure out here should work for any `Movie` pojo Schema. I have also heard about something called `BeanAwareUtils`, is that something that could be used here?

Comment: if i understand, why don't you check in `@RequestBody` user sent `"completed" : [...some old stuff],` this stuff or not? , if not you can set it right?

Comment: That would be manual way to do it I guess. I mean like I said, what if I have 100 fields in my `WatchList`pojo? Is there a way to automatically check the fields that user sent and only update those in my old pojo? There must be a jackson way of doing it or maybe some other library. With manual way like you said, it would take me more than 100 lines or some extra magic with polymorphism making my application more complex. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that I found after searching online. You can use `BeanUtils`. Here is maven dependency for it(make sure to check the updated version when you are using it).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you need to create another class(className can be anything) as follows:

```
public class NullAwareBeanArrayUtilsBean extends BeanUtilsBean {

    @Override
    public void copyProperty(Object dest, String name, Object value) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        if (value == null || (value instanceof List<?> && ((List<?>) value).size() <= 0))
            return;
        super.copyProperty(dest, name, value);
    }

}
```

And when you want to use it anywhere else in your code, use it like this:

```
BeanUtilsBean notNull = new NullAwareBeanArrayUtilsBean();
notNull.copyProperties(dest, original);
```

**Explanation**

`BeanUtils` is a library which has one method to copy properties from one pojo to another pojo. It has a `copyProperties` method which internally calls `copyProperty` method. Here we have created a subclass called `NullAwareBeanArrayUtilsBean` which extends `BeanUtilsBean` and we have given a custom functionality to one of its methods named `copyProperty`.

Remember that this method is called internally from `copyProperties` method. You can try console logging `name` in this `copyProperty` method to see that `name` refers to `each` field from your pojo.

**What are we doing in the custom overriden copyProperty method?**

Consider this line

```
BeanUtilsBean notNull = new NullAwareBeanArrayUtilsBean();
notNull.copyProperties(dest, original);
```

Here we are saying that we want to copy stuff from `original` pojo to `dest` pojo.

For each field in our pojo, `copyProperties` internally calls our custom overriden method named `copyProperty`.

Consider `copyProperty` method's first line:

```
if (value == null || (value instanceof List<?> && ((List<?>) value).size() <= 0)) return;
```

Here we are checking if `value is null` or `if value is a List` and is that `list empty`, then we are skipping the copying operation. Therefore with this approach, if user sends a partial object from postman(for instance), we will copy only those fields in which the user has put some stuff all the while not changing other fields(which already have old content) in our destination pojo.